# Accessing Recovery Mode

Tags: recovery-mode

How do I access the recovery mode in Ubuntu 18.04? I don't see any form of grub bootloader when the system boots - it just goes straight into the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access recovery mode, as soon as the system boots up, you'll need to hold down SHIFT. You should then see the GNU Grub menu. From here, chose "Advanced Options", then select the option that says "Ubuntu .. recovery mode" or something similar.

Comment: On UEFI systems it is usually ESC key.

Comment: That's strange. Shift works fine for me whether it is BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMassey this works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped you!