# Ubuntu 18.04 boots forever, how can I check systemctl?

Tags: boot, 18.04

I started my Ubuntu 18.04 this morning and it is booting for over 20 minutes now. I already figured out, that by pressing escape, I can get into a mode where I am able to see what is going on.

It says:

```
"failed to mount media/m-proc" see systemctl status "media-m\\x2dproc.mount" for details.
```

But I don't know how to do that. How can I access a terminal or something if it is still booting? Sorry, for this very basic question!

Comment: Do you have any external devices attached? If yes, try and remove them and reboot. Might be an error on an external device.

Comment: I can't remove them.. they belong to my workplace and I connect to them if I work on my linux. Usually, I mount them, after I start the computer..

Comment: What you want basically, is to enter recovery mode, which is explained here: [Accessing Recovery Mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167741/accessing-recovery-mode)

Comment: Thank you! but how do I get there? just forcefully stop the computer by pressing the on off button and start again? also.. I still dont understand how I can check systmctl if the booting is faling..

Comment: If that's your only option - yes?