# Missing letter in the username

Tags: username

I installed Ubuntu for the first time a few days ago and it all went smoothly.
However in the terminal, there always is one letter missing from my username.
I checked in my settings but there it shows my correct name.

`whoami` returns `mbra` and `echo $HOME` returns `mbra` as well.

I know its not a major issue but it would feel a lot better if I was able to fix this.
In the following image, it's supposed to read umbra twice:

[image: It's supposed to read umbra twice]

Comment: Is the letter missing in your username, or only in the shell prompt? please add the output of `id -un`

Comment: @steeldriver the output is mbra, but in the settings my name is fully displayed.

Comment: @user68186 i did that, both return mbra, how do i fix that?

Comment: Note, if you follow the answer with the highest votes, Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 instead of Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to the TTY. Alternately use recovery mode.

Comment: @user68186 No, it doesnt help, when i try the usermod it just returns "user mbra is currently used by process 1571", so no luck there.

Comment: That probably means you are still logged in as `mbra`. You have to log out and either login as `root` in the TTY, or restart the computer in the recovery mode and use the commands.

Comment: See [Accessing Recovery Mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167741/accessing-recovery-mode) and select the option for "Drop to root shell prompt". See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode for more details.